# Get model data based on pivot table column

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

```
# TABLES:
# kids: name, birthday, active
# chores: name, start_age, number_of_kids_required
# chore_kid: chore_id, kid_id, chore_date
```

Kid.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Kid extends Model
{
    public function chores(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Chore')
            ->withPivot('chore_date')
            ->withTimestamps();    
    }
}
```

Chore.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Kid;

class Chore extends Model
    public function kids(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Kid')
            ->withPivot('chore_date')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

With belongs to many I can grab the chores with assigned kids and the pivot table having the requested chore date:

```
$chore->kids()->wherePivot('chore_date', $date);
```

How can I get all the chores with the same `chore_date` without limiting it to the kids that are assigned to a specific chore.

How do I do this?  This is my guess at this but it doesn't work:

```
Chore::wherePivot('chore_date', $date);
```

I have tried other combinations, but can't seem to find the right syntax.

Comment: "without limiting it to the kids that are assigned to a specific chore" --> what is this means ?? you want get only a chore with specific date ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

controller

```
$chore = Chore::whereHas('kids', function ($query) use ($date){
   $query->where('chore_date','=', $date );
})->get();
```

with that you'll get chore with specific date. hope that help.

Comment: To get `$date` to pass in I had to add `funciton($query) use ($date) {`

This satisfies what I asked for though, thank you.